# SELECT statement using set Algebra

Tags: sql, oracle

Having these two tables:

**DEPARTMENT**

```
DNAME
-----------
RESEARCH
   IT
 SCIENCE
```

**DEPTLOC**

```
DNAME       LOCATION
----------------------
RESEARCH      BOSTON
   IT         LONDON
RESEARCH      DALLAS
 SCIENCE      BOSTON
```

my question is to find the `DNAME` where only located either in BOSTON or LONDON but not in both cities.

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT D.DNAME 
FROM DEPARTMENT D 
INNER JOIN DEPTLOC L ON L.DNAME = D.DNAME 
WHERE L.CITY='BOSTON' OR L.CITY='DALLAS'
GROUP BY D.DNAME
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1;
```

It works but I don't think it is correct as my question stated:

```
"Implementing set algebra SELECT statements"
```

So what should I change in order to get the correct result using the right statement?
Output should be like:

```
   DNAME
-----------
    IT
  SCIENCE
```

Comment: Beats me. Go back and ask your prof what he means by "set algebra" in the context of a relational database. Best of luck.

Comment: i can't get what you mean. maybe i can't understand clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I where to guess you are asked to provide a solution using set operations like `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `DIFFERENCE (MINUS or EXCEPT)`. If A is departments located in Boston and B is departments located in London then (A - B) U (B - A) is one solution

Answer (score 1):

Set Algebra means using set operators: `UNION, MINUS, INTERSECT`.

Comment: can teach me for my example above? i just try to learn it as well. thanks you