# Compare duplicate value in the same field

Tags: sql

Here is my table

```
DNAME           CITY
---------------------
OPERATOR        BOSTON
RESEARCH        BOSTON
RESEARCH        DALLAS
SALES           DALLAS
SALES           BOSTON
INSURANCE       NEW YORK
```

What i wanted to do find the names of all departments located either in BOSTON or in DALLAS and not in both cities.

The expected result should be show only 'OPERATOR'.

How is the select statement i should use in the sql query? Should i use UNION or INTERSECT?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406562/select-statement-using-set-algebra, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406864/select-clause-and-return-yes-or-no-only

Comment: looks like a possible college assignment to me! You guys all from the same class ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
select DNAME
from YourTable
WHERE City in ('BOSTON', 'DALLAS')
GROUP BY DNAME
having count(distinct City) = 1
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ef30a/2)

Comment: @RajaRajendraprasath  ?? Don't understand your question. It's a count distinct. You may just try in sqlfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

then what if the duplicate values?

```
DNAME           CITY
---------------------
OPERATOR        BOSTON
RESEARCH        BOSTON
RESEARCH        DALLAS
SALES           DALLAS
SALES           DALLAS
INSURANCE       NEW YORK
```

result will be like this as per your query right?

```
Name     Count
OPERATOR 1
SALES    2
```

Comment: Well, as it looks like a comment to my answer : you will have SALES, yes, but count 1, as I use a `count(distinct City)`, not a `count(City)`

Comment: Can it be done with Algebra select statement?